# Bash: Extract variable value from string

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I'd need to extract the value of a variable "error" from a log file. Here's a sample line:

```
WARN (Periodic Recovery) IJ000906: error=15 check server.log
```

I'd need to capture the value of "error". Looking on similar answers, I've come up with:

```
echo "WARN (Periodic Recovery) IJ000906: error=15 check server.log" |  grep -P '\d+ (error=?)' -o
```

However it does not produce any value. Can you recommend a working solution for this case?

Comment: `?` is an operator, not a wild-card. You are trying to match the string `error` followed by an optional `=`.

Comment: and you're trying to match digits before a blank before `error` when  the character that precedes the blank before `error` is `:`, not a digit.

Comment: Why do you have to use POSIX shell? With bash or zsh, you would have much more possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo "WARN (Periodic Recovery) IJ000906: error=15 check server.log" | sed 's/.*error=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
15
```

Answer (score 4):

For a perl-compatible regular expression, you're looking for a "lookbehind" assertion.

To find digits that are preceded by the string "error=", you want:

```sh
echo "$line" | grep -o -P '(?<=error=)\d+'    # => 15
```

See [the `pcresyntax(3)` man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man3/pcresyntax.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `grep`:

```sh
s='WARN (Periodic Recovery) IJ000906: error=15 check server.log'
grep -oP '\berror=\K\d+' <<< "$s"

15
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Match word boundary
- `error=`: Match `error=` text
- `\K`: Reset matched info
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits and print it

Comment: I'd suggest replacing `\d+: ` with `\b` -- I don't think that the previous digits-colon-space are part of the requirements.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman! Reason why I used that because OP was using `\d+ (error=?)` as regex pattern i.e. trying to match 1+digits before whitespace + `error`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
WARN (Periodic Recovery) IJ000906: error=15 check server.log
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="error=[0-9]+"}{print substr($1,7)}' file.txt
```

output

```
15
```

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that column is `error=` followed by 1 or more digits using field pattern (`FPAT`), for every line print first field starting from 7th charater, using [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) string function. `7` as `error=` has 6 characters. Note: this solution will print first occurence of `error=`value for each line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` >= 3.0.

```
v='WARN (Periodic Recovery) IJ000906: error=15 check server.log'

[[ $v =~ error=([0-9]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Output:

```
15
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F'error=| check' '{print $2}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting field separators as `error=` OR  `check` for all the lines. Then printing 2nd field of line, which will print value after `error=` and before  `check` as per shown samples.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `match` function of `awk` here.

```
awk 'match($0,/error=[^[:space:]]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)}' Input_file
```